# Laravel Checking if a Dynamic property is set

Tags: php, laravel-5, dynamic-properties

I have a class `foo` that belongs to `bar`.

within `foo` I have:

```
public function bar(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bar');
}
```

I have an object `$foo` who's `bar_id` is `null`.

Within `Foo`, I have an if statment:

```
if ($this->bar->id == 1){ echo "in if"; }
```

Not surprisingly I was getting a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.  So I added a call to `isset`.  But now the code inside the if is never being evaluated because the if is always false.  My new if looks like:

```
if(isset($this->bar) && $this->bar->id == 1){ echo "in if"; }
```

After setting the `bar_id` I am still not going into the `if`.  When I try to `print bar_id` I see the value is not null.  Why am I not going into this if?

Comment: Looks wrong. How can Bar belong to Bar? Or maybe it's convoluted.

Comment: Foo belongs to bar.  The dynamic property is in the Foo class.

Comment: Does the Model bar have a column named "id" ?

Comment: Yes it does... it is the primary key and the foo primary key references it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Apparently `isset` doesn't call the dynamic function, which means that the value doesn't get loaded which means it is still `null`.  To get around it I did the following:

```
$bar = $this->bar();
if (isset($this-> bar) && $this->bar->id == 1) { echo "in if"; }
```

Since I am calling $this->bar() before it gets to the `isset` function, when `isset` checks the property, it returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a safer check:

```
if($this->bar instanceof \App\Models\Bar) {
    echo 'in if';
}
```

This would check if the `bar` property is set and the according relation is instantiated.